# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. Process 'command java.exe finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: java, android

I know this question has been asked many times but i am still not able to find the solution. I check for each and every possible duplication library but didn't find it. Here is my Manifest

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.dp.myquest"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 16
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile files('libs/abs.jar')
compile files('libs/activation.jar')
compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar')
compile files('libs/android-query-full.0.26.7.jar')
compile files('libs/App42_ANDROID_SDK_3.0.1.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-collections4-4.0.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-net-3.3.jar')
compile files('libs/mail.jar')
compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.0.jar')
compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3.jar')
compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.19.0'
}
```

Comment: can you please add the complete stacktrace of the error

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with duplicate, the problem is android has a limit of 64k method for an dex file in app.
You need to enable multidex. 
This is how you can do it 
http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: I enabled it still same error. This code is working fine in eclipse.